# ensuring all the ids value in the hashMap are different?

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap, hashset, bluej

The method below (`generateID()`)it generate a random  ids, And when i store students in the `HashMap` i want to check if the generated id is not exist in the hashMap value and if its exists I want to generate a new id and then store it, The problem with the method store sometimes it does not store all the student because some student might have the same id and this is not allowed, So what is the best why to check that all ids are uniqe and if there is duplication the method generateid will be called again util all the ids are uniqe and then it will store it, I want to  ensure that the ids values produced by `generateId()` are all different

```
 private String generateId(String perfix, int numberaOfDigits)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<numberaOfDigits;i++)
        {
            perfix +=  randomGenerator.nextInt(9)+ 1; 

        }
        return perfix;
    }



 public void store(Student student) 
    {   

        int index = 0;


            studentMap.setId(generateId("AB-",1));

            while(index <= studentMap.size())

            {
                for(Student stu : studentMap.values() )

                {
                    if(student.getStduentID().equals(stu.getStduentID()))

                    {
                        student.setId(generateId("AB-",1));
                    } 

                }
                index++;
            }
        }
        studentMap.put(student.getStduentID(),student);

    }
```

Comment: Random or not random - you can't have both: why not just a sequence of numbers - increment it by a random number each time if you want something "like" random.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `containsKey()` method to check if an ID is already in use as key

Comment: yeah I have used that but is there a better way without using the class methods

Comment: there are other ways like iterating over the `keySet()` and check if there is a key that matches your ID but i don't think those would be better. btw didn't we have this question just yesterday?

Comment: thanks for your answer Okay after creating a unique id student and I wrote then to a file,for example if create Student  and add it to the list.  How can i be sure that the id that has been allocated for the new Student has not already been allocated to one of the Student in the file Student_data.txt ?

Comment: use your crystal ball... or just keep a list with all used IDs and check it first whenever you assign a new ID

Answer (score 0):

You can `get` from the map with the generated Id, if it returns `null`, then it doesn't exist 
yet.

```
Map<Long, Object> myMap = new HashMap<Long, Object>();
Long id = generateRandomId()
Object value = getMyObjectValue();

while(myMap.get(id) != null){
    id = generateRandomId();
}

myMap.put(id, value);
```

Comment: @LibyaGhassar, I edited my answer with an example, it seems smelly though. Don't understand why you need the Id to be random like that. and not just an incremented counter of some sort

Comment: Okay after creating a unique id student and I wrote then to a file,for example if create Student  and add it to the list.  How can i be sure that the id that has been allocated for the new Student has not already been allocated to one of the Student in the file Student_data.txt ?

Comment: Now that's a whole different problem, it seems to me you're trying to control a Primary Key of some sort. You should use a normal increment, it would make your life much easier

Comment: i know but thats mean I all change my whole codes, I think I have to read the file first and then maybe to store it in a local variable and then compare it with the new Id which generted for a new student but I am not sure how to do this thanks

Comment: The thing about it being random, is that you don't have any natural order, so you have to compare to every Id on your file. Sorry, but I believe you should rewrite it while you still can

Comment: okay can you not even explain it, I think I have to do in my way :

Comment: To do it in the way you want it now, you would have to read through the entire file, checking id by id. It's the only way to do it. If you used an increment, you could read the last Id from the file, and continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use an UUID. Or a sequence as already answered

Comment: no I want to do it by my self without using the UUI thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

If that's actually a Map implementation, you should be able to use .containsKey().  The problem is that, depending on how well written your ID generator is, this can cause significant performance issues over time.  Say you have a 6 digit ID, and in a few years 80000 students have passed through the system.  How many guesses will it need before it finds one of the remaining 20000 available keys?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try following implementation to get unique random number each time.

1. Add items to the list .
2. Use `Collections.shuffle(list);` to shuffle the list .
3. Iterate over list and get random number each time from the given range. (For below case range is from 0 to numberOfStudent-1).

   ```
   int numberOfStudent = 10;
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudent; i++) 
       list.add(i);    

   Collections.shuffle(list);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would eliminate the `generateId()` method altogether, and simply do this:

```
private int id;
```

then:

```
student.setId(id++);
```